# Overloading [] operator of Matrix class with const

Tags: c++

I'm having some troubles trying to understand the following.
While writing a simple Matrix class with `vector` and templates I tried to overload the `[]` operator to acces the elements. This is the class

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> values;
    int rows, cols;
public:
    Matrix(int row, int col) : rows(row), cols(col) {
        values = std::vector<std::vector<T>>(rows, std::vector<T>(cols));
    }

    std::vector<T>& operator[] (const int i) const{
        return values[i];
    }
};
```

Note that I'm returning a `vector<T>`, so I can use the double indexing easily.
The problem I'm having is that , when trying to call the operator, there is the following error:

`Cannot realize the conversion from 'const_Ty' to 'std::vector<T,std::allocator<T>> &`

And I have no clue where this conversion is happening. I'm not modifying anything from the class, so I thought I should use `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method being `const` means that the member variables are treated as `const` and can’t be modified.

You’re currently returning a `std::vector<T>&` which means a caller could modify it (but that goes against the `const` qualifier).

Change the return type to `const std::vector<T>&`, so that callers can’t modify the returned value.

Comment: Could you please be more explicit about this? I see it works, but I think this answer doesn't show why it works.

Comment: It might be more accurate to say "The method being `const` means that the member variables are _treated as_ `const`".  You therefore cannot return a non-const reference to `values`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense now. Don't know why the post  is closed now, tho